# Nginx cache file check

Tags: caching, nginx, webserver

how to check what file is cached by nginx?. Is there any option to decode the nginx cache key value ?.

I thought, it generating the key file as MD5 hash. but I'm unable to decode that value through MD5 decoder.

proxy_cache_key $scheme$proxy_host$uri$is_args$args;

Answer (score 3):

At the very beginning of NGINX cache file there is a string looking like "KEY: *URL*". So you can just grep it.